# Using Imagemagick to convert PDFs having rasters in them results in white backgrounds behind the sections covered by the rasters

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I tried to use ImageMagick (v6.8.9-9 Q16) to convert a PDF containing a PNG file embedded in it to a PNG file.

The [original PNG file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bsrkrovgb3x4018/original_dice.png?dl=0) had a transparent background. In the [PDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5y0ggnapi63j3tq/dice.pdf?dl=0) too it appears fine. But in the [PNG obtained after conversion](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/khagakm7bfryc1k/converted_dice.png?dl=0), the area originally occupied by the PNG in the PDF has a white background. Please see the links for more clarity.

The command I ran is as follows:

`convert -colorspace sRGB dice.pdf converted_dice.png`

I also tried setting the `-transparent white` switch but it ends up taking out whites that were actually required in the final image.

Are there any extra switches or parameters to pass to `convert` in order to get rid of just this white background?

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"PDF containing a PNG file"*. Once an image is inside the PDF, it is raster data (and there are various compression schemes for this chunks of raster data -- one of them happening to be the same as JPEG uses). It may have been a PNG file in its former life, but it is no more. There is no way to discover this from the PDF data alone. Of course you can extract the raster data and convert them into PNG again. Or to TIFF, GIF, JPEG,... If you don't have the foreknowledge about the PDF's creation, you would not know about the contained images' previous life form...

Answer (score 3):

Kurt already explains the whole thing in great detail. So here is just how to assemble an image with ImageMagick after running it through `pdfimages -png`

```
pdfimages -png my.pdf my
```

This resluts in two files

```
identify my-0*png
  my-000.png PNG 360x310 360x310+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 3.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
  my-001.png PNG 360x310 360x310+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 9.44KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

`my-001.png` is the image labeled `smask` in `pdfimages -list`. To reassemble the image back to it's original form use `-compose CopyOpacity` with the ImageMagick command `composite`

```
composite -compose CopyOpacity my-001.png my-000.png my-reassembled.png
```

See also http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#masks for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach to this task cannot work.

The command you used will convert the complete letter-sized PDF page (612 x 792 pt) into a PNG image.

However, the original size of the image embedded in the PDF page (612 x 792 pt) is 800 x 600 pixels. This can be seen by running `pdfimages -list`:

```
pdfimages -list dice.pdf 
 page num  type width height color comp bpc  enc interp object ID x-ppi y-ppi  size ratio
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   0 image   800   600   rgb     3   8  image   no     12  0    72    72  277K   20%
    1   1 smask   800   600  gray     1   8  image   no     12  0    72    72 50.1K   11%
```

So this is the first problem when converting the PDF page: it does not give your the correct size of the contained images.

The second, more fundamental problem however is: any image you get from converting a PDF page is the ***combination*** of all PDF objects overlayed on each other as they are from the page area. (Of course you could crop only part of the page -- but this gives you likewise the combination of all PDF objects from the cropped area...). The results of this you've encountered when you tried to convert all white pixels into transparent ones: since the originally different objects are merged into one representation of pixels, you can no longer discriminate between them as required.

You should take a ***different approach*** and use a different tool to extract the image: use `pdfimages` (the tool used above with the `-list` parameter to display image properties from the PDF's pages). As you can see, there are **two** images list: one is an RGB raster image, the other is a grayscale raster image, dubbed as type `smask` (softmask).

Here is a command to extract both images as PNG:

```
 pdfimages -png dice.pdf dice-images
```

This will extract the two:

1. `dice-images-0000.png` (a color image)
2. `dice-images-0001.png` (a grayscale image)

(**Note:** Only very recent versions of `pdfimages`, the Poppler version, will let your extract the images as PNG. Within the PDF there is no such thing as PNG. There are only raster data, compressed with different methods. Older versions will only be able to extract images as PPM or PNM. This does not have any influence on what I describe below. Even if you extract PPM/PNM images, these two files can still be processed as described below...)

Below is a side-by-side, scaled-down montage of the two:

[image: Color image from PDF (left) with associated soft-mask (right)]

As you can see, the image itself does not have a transparent background, but a white one. (It does not have an Alpha channel.) Within the PDF format, these two images are used in combination to create transparent areas:

1. what appears completely black in the softmask (right) means: this pixel of the real image (left) is meant to be fully transparent.
2. what appears completely white in the softmask (right) means: this pixel of the real image (left) is meant to be fully opaque.
3. what appears in a shade of gray in the softmask (right) means: this pixel of the real image (left) is meant to be partially transparent (in line with its level of gray/black).

To combine these two files (color image and grayscale softmask) back into one PNG with transparency, you can employ ImageMagick now...

Comment: "To combine these two files (color image and grayscale softmask) back into one PNG with transparency, you can employ ImageMagick now..." -- what's the ImageMagick command to do this? i.e. convert -???